# .NET Core - Entity Framework - Unexpected Behaviour with Eager Loading Include()

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, .net-core, eager-loading

### Initial Query

If I run the following query I get the result below, `CityTranslation.IdFkLanguageNavigation` will be `null`. 
`CityTranslation.IdFkCityNavigation` on the other hand will be populated. Considering they are both on the same hierarchical level.

```
    var data = await _context.City
                        .Include(x => x.CityTranslation)
                        .Include(c => c.IdFkCountryNavigation)
                        .ToListAsync();
```

I've tried using `ThenInclude()` after `.Include(x => x.CityTranslation)` but it wouldn't let me use the Language Property.

---

### Altered Query

With the query below, I do get some really unexpected results. Once I debug through `data2`, suddently the `Language` navigation property from my **first query result** gets populated!

This only works if I call `ToList()` on the second query, otherwise it still doesn't get populated. I have to assume the data is shared across the whole EF context but how can I leverage this behaviour without sending a second query to the database? I am really stunned by this behaviour and would appreciate any reference or explanation.

```
                var data = await _context.City
                    .Include(x => x.CityTranslation)
                    .Include(c => c.IdFkCountryNavigation).ToListAsync();

                var data2 = _context.CityTranslation.Include(c => c.IdFkLanguageNavigation).ToListAsync();
```

---

### Context

I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` version `1.1.2`

---

### City

```
public partial class City
{
    public City()
    {
        CityTranslation = new HashSet<CityTranslation>();
    }

    public int IdPkCity { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public int? IdFkCountry { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CityTranslation> CityTranslation { get; set; }
    public virtual Country IdFkCountryNavigation { get; set; }
```

---

### City Translations

```
public partial class CityTranslation
{
    public int IdPkCityTranslation { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }
    public int IdFkCity { get; set; }
    public int IdFkLanguage { get; set; }

    public virtual City IdFkCityNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Language IdFkLanguageNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Language

```
public partial class Language
{
    public Language()
    {
        AirportTranslation = new HashSet<AirportTranslation>();
        CityTranslation = new HashSet<CityTranslation>();
        CountryTranslation = new HashSet<CountryTranslation>();
    }

    public int IdPkLanguage { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AirportTranslation> ATranslation{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CityTranslation> CTranslation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CountryTranslation> C2Translation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `.Include(x => x.CityTranslation).ThenInclude(x => x.IdFkLanguageNavigation)` should work. Just there are Intellisense issues with `ThenInclude` method.

Comment: your kidding right ... ? That wouldn't really explain why on the same hierarchical level the city navigation property gets loaded without any additional effort. I will give it a try tomorrow morning. Appreciate your input.

Comment: Haha, I'm was totally serious :) What about why some data is loaded w/o additional effort, it's basically explained by the following **Tip** from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data): *Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded.*

Comment: Well it worked but I am still baffled by the solution - anyways thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, just paste this.

```
// Hits the database only once
var data = await _context.City
    .Include(x => x.CityTranslation)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.IdFkLanguageNavigation)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Now, as to why your second query loads the `Language` navigation property of your first query, you have to look into how EntityFramework works as a whole, read up on explicit loading.

Here's an example of explicit loading.

```
// Hits the database once.
var data = await _context.City
    .Include(x => x.CityTranslation)
    .ToListAsync();

var cityTranslationIds = data.Select(x => x.CityTranslation.IdPkCityTranslation);

// Hits the database the second time.
// Language navigation property will be loaded onto the data variable above
_context.Language
    .Where(x => cityTranslateIds.Contains(x.IdPkLanguage))
    .Load();

// Your second query, what you did here is essentially the same as the above's Load(), 
// but the Load() is better suited for your intention.
var data2 = await _context.CityTranslation
    .Include(c => c.IdFkLanguageNavigation)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Depending on the situation, you need to choose between eager and explicit loading for best performance.